# In Excel, is there a way to set the default transparency of shapes?

Tags: excel, transparency, shapes

I want to use shapes to put arrows on my worksheet, and I want the arrows to always by 75% transparent, and I don't want to click each one and manually change it each time.  Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Ah!  I didn't want to mess with vba for this.

But you did help me find a way to do it that seems to be working.  You got me looking for the word 'Default'.  I drew my arrow, right clicked it, chose 'Format Shape', changed the transparency to 75%, then right click the arrow again and chose 'Set as Default Line' now they all seem to be coming out with 75%.

Answer (score 0):

While not 75% transparent, you can achieve 50% by changing the Default Shape Style: Create a shape, and you will get a "Shape Format" contextual tab on the ribbon.  If you Right Click on an a preset, you can set it as the Default.  There are 0%, 50% and 100% transparent presets.

I do not know of a way to create a *custom* style though.

You could also just create all of your shapes, and then use VBA to change the transparency of every shape on the Worksheet at the same time:

```vb
Sub ChangeShapeTransparency()
    'Put in the Code Page of the Worksheet that you want to change,
    'then press F5 to run
    Dim shp As Shape
    
    For Each shp In Me.Shapes
        shp.Fill.Transparency = 0.75 'Fill is 75% transparent
        shp.Line.Transparency = 0.75 'Outline is 75% transparent
    Next shp
End Sub
```

(You can then delete the code, once it has done its job)